# Back Key button press not working on samsung phone

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm using a Samsung GT-5330 for installing my android app. I need to return to the first screen if a user presses the back button after confirmation of data.

I'm using the following code:

```
  public override bool OnKeyDown(Android.Views.Keycode keyCode, Android.Views.KeyEvent e) {


          if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(HotelSearchPage));
              StartActivity(i);

        }
        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);


         }
```

This works fine on my emulator, but is not working on my device.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong:  `if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)`

Right:  `if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)`

So you can try:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And as [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) is available since API level 5, you can use it too.

Comment: I have tried using the OnBackPressed() Method, this however, is still not working on my device. I'm using Mono fro Android, so, keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK is not valid here.

Comment: @user1702272 why don't you people mentioned in question that you are using different framework.

Answer (score 1):

use `onBackPressed()` method and try